# Strange behavior with Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, json, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I have an API developed with Django Rest Framework. I have a model with some nullable fields, they are defined with the setting

```
required = False
```

in the serializer. When I want to update an instance of this model, with a PUT request to the api, I succeed If I send the request parameters as form data, but If I send a json with request payload, the API returns a 400 bad request, stating that my non-required parameters can not be null, as in:

```
"gender":["This field may not be null."]
```

When I inspect the requests, the one with form data (which succeeds) sends:

```
email=abc%40abc.com&first_name=John&gender=&id=13&image_url=http%3A%2F%&last_name=Doe
```

And the one with json data (which fails with a 400 error) sends:

```
{
    "id":13,
    "email":"abc@abc.com",
    "first_name":"John",
    "last_name":"Doe",
    "image_url":"http://...",
    "gender":null
}
```

Any ideas what could be the reason?

EDIT: Model and serializer fields for gender:

In models.py:

```
gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES, null=True, blank=True)
```

In serializers:

```
gender = serializers.CharField(required=False, source='userprofile.gender')
```

EDIT:

From the docs:

```
Note: If your <field_name> is declared on your serializer with the parameter required=False then this validation step will not take place if the field is not included.
```

So validation step will take place if this fields is included, but still, as it is defined as nullable in the db, it should pass the validation.

Comment: Have you tried removing it from your request data?

Comment: @Gocht It works if I remove it from the request data, but I use a backbone application as the client, which puts all the fields by default. I can try and find a way to remove it from the request, but I want to understand the real problem behind, as this error shouldn't arise at all with required=False

Answer (score 0):

When you mark a field as `required=False` it means that your request data can miss that field and value.

You send this in your request:

```
email=abc%40abc.com&first_name=John&gender=&id=13&image_url=http%3A%2F%&last_name=Doe
```

So you're sending a value for `gender`, I guess your problem is in your models, where `gender` is not marked as `null=True`. If you remove `gender` from your request, this should work.

```
email=abc%40abc.com&first_name=John&id=13&image_url=http%3A%2F%&last_name=Doe
```

Comment: It is defined as nullable in the model as well, I'm updating the question to add the model data

Answer (score 0):

There is a serializer option, allow_null in Django Rest Framework. I had to set it to True for nullable fields in the serializer. It started working after that.

```
gender = serializers.CharField(required=False, allow_null=True,  source='userprofile.gender'
```

Though I still do not know why I need to set this flag explicitly, as the field is already defined as nullable in the model.

Comment: DRf doesn't add magically flags to explicitly defined fields.

Comment: I don't think there is need for a magic in that, as the field is defined with options null=True and blank=True in the source model

Comment: This is magic because if that was true, you could affect an explicitly defined field by playing on the model side. Going to create a *lot* of confusion for most users as the API behavior will change while it shouldn't unless you explicitly add all the possible default values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use in **serializers.CharField** the options default.  This way must work